# Link with pseudo element double tap issue in iOS

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the effect of a scrolling line beneath anchor links to meet a client brief - I stupidly imagined a bit of CSS3 would easily achieve this without any bother, so I've setup something along the lines of the following code, and spent the past hour banging my head on the desk due to a very annoying bug I don't understand.

Everything works great on desktop, but on mobile (both iOS and Android) I experience an issue when I select a link - **First click, the animation runs, and I have to click a second time to trigger the link** (same happens with below codepen). It's baffling me and I wonder if anyone can shine any light on things for me!!?

http://codepen.io/pablodancer/pen/ZLJVOP

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
li a:after {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  content: "";
  z-index: -3;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
li a:hover:after,
li.active a:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="http:www.nme.com">nme</a></li>
  <li><a href="http:www.bbc,co.uk">bbc</a></li>
  <li><a href="">blah3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">blah4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">blah5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tested your codepen on my android and everything works fine. I just had to change your broken links. http//:www.nme.com you're missing forward slashes.

Comment: cool - i'm using a live iphone6 to test but an older Android via browserstack - i'm guessing yours is a new android?

Comment: Android version 4.4.2, Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: fair enough - its definitely knackered on IOS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the double tap issue is only related to iOS. What I normally do is to simply hide the pseudo element on touch devices, either approach below will work.

(1) Using CSS media queries, it works in iOS 9+ and Android 5+.

```
@media (hover: none) {
  li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

(2) Using a bit of Javascript + CSS:

```
(function(html) {
  html.className += ('ontouchstart' in window) ? ' touch ' : ' no-touch ';
})(document.documentElement);
```

---

```
.touch li a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

In addition, if you wish to keep the active style, you can use selector `li:not(.active) a:after`. You may also want to set `li {vertical-align: top;}` so the items can lineup nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a non-standard behavior adopted by WebKit on IOS.

Weird (but common) issue needs a weird (and simple) hack, here is how I solved it with only CSS and bullet-proof browser support.

Basically, the magic is using `transforms` and IOS/WebKit will not consider as hidden the pseudo element, so it will not force the double-tap behavior when it's shown on hover:

```
li a:after {
  /* keep the element 'visible' and with a size */
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  ...
  /* then 'hide' it with a transform */
  transform: scaleX(0);
  ...
  /* add a nice transition */
  transition: transform 600ms ease;
}

li a:hover:after {
  /* 'show' the element by resetting the transform */
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Till now, it seems to do the trick, why? because the size of a transformed element is not computed in the reflow of the page :)